# Find the location of the royal artifacts

Tags: mathematics, cipher, story, number-property

**London, 13:20**

While media and experts are still baffled on how Inspector Arbor caught Norman Erdmann (*can you solve it? See [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94133/catching-the-thief-before-its-too-late/))* Arbor himself has no time to rest.

Police has already questioned Erdmann about the whereabouts of the stolen royal artifacts but has only earned laughter from the suspect. "I will only talk to Mr. Arbor", Erdmann continuously exclaimed.

His wish was granted and soon Inspector Arbor arrived at the Police station and entered the interrogation room.

"Ah, Arbor! Finally we see us face to face. I got to give you my sincere congratulations for catching me."

"Stop your sweet talk, I want to know where the artifacts are", Arbor said angrily, while thinking of an alternate reality, where he could enjoy the beautiful Sunday at the Park.

"Very well, 265!", Erdmann said amused.

"Oh please God no, another number bulls-?!"

"Inspector, don't pretend that you're not loving riddles"

He was right. Arbor did in fact love these riddles. But not on weekends!

"Alright, but this number won't lead me to anything"

"You're right. The message I sent you will lead you there. If I were you, I'd be quick. The royal artifacts will be removed in 25 minutes by my subordinates."

"What are you talking about? You don't even have a phone he-", Arbor stopped because his phone vibrated. He, in fact, received a message which read...

```
11101110111011101010100111011101000100010001010001000001010101000100010101000100
10101100100011001001010000111011101110111010101000100101010101000101010001000001
00010100010100010101000100101010011000100110001000001110111011101000111011101001
1101000101010001000100000
```

*(Note: Newlines are only for better reading. The message was transmitted in one string)*

"Quick, bring me pencil and paper", Arbor shouted at the young Policeman next to him.

"You found it out already?", Erdmann acted surprised.

"Sure, it doesn't look alien to me"

"As expected", Erdmann now seemed pleased.

After 15 minutes Inspector Arbor cracked the message and contacted authorities in the United States.

*Where are the royal artifacts located?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are at:

> 285 Fulton, NY

as shown by

> dividing the string into five equally-sized rows, and shading all the 1s.
>  [image]

Comment: Nicely done! You've been extremely quick!